# Ping localcode.net could not be found

Tags: networking, ping

There is a public DNS for `lcoalcode.net`. It can be found [here](https://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=a%3Alocalcode.net&run=toolpage). It's a public DNS for all developers out there. It resolves to `127.0.0.1`

For some reason, I can no longer `ping localcode.net`. When I do that, I get:

> Ping request could not find host localcode.net. Please check the name
>   and try again.

When I run `tracert localcode.net`; I get the following:

> Unable to resolve target system name localcode.net.

**EDIT**

My ISP is Comcast. I asked two friends of mine on two different ISPs to try to ping `localcode.net`. The Verizon ISP worked; but the Comcast didn't.

What is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer.
Comcast is filtering DNS. Jerks!

Change your Primary DNS in your router's setting to `8.8.8.8` to Google's public DNS.